# jsPDF always return jsPDF PubSub Error on console

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jspdf

I have a button for save html page. When user click button i want to trigger jsPDF functions but it returns "jspdf PubSub Error" and generated pdf file is blank.

```
 var doc = new jsPDF();
 var specialElementHandlers = {
   '#editor': function(element, renderer){
    return true;
   }
 };

 $('.voucher-actions__save').click(function () {
   doc.fromHTML($('body').html(), 0, 0, {
    'width': 170,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
   });
   //doc.save('voucher.pdf');
   console.log(doc);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below code and it should work

```
// #clientPrintContent is the element id which contains print content
// Print Docs
function printPDF() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var elementHandler = {
        '#clientPrintContent': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    var source = document.getElementById("clientPrintContent");
    doc.fromHTML(
      source,
      15,
      15,
      {
          'width': 180, 'elementHandlers': elementHandler
      });
    // Output 
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
}
```

You can add CDN hosted library from  [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-THVO/sM0mFD9h7dfSndI6TS0PgAGavwKvB5hAxRRvc0o9cPLohB0wb/PTA7LdUHs" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with jsPDF:

[image]

Downgrading jsPDF from v1.3.5 to v1.3.1 helped me.

Versions I am using now:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```